# Error: Uncaught [TypeError: parentStateSetter is not a function]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

So, my app starts up fine when I run yarn start. However, when I run yarn test, one of my tests fails and I get this following error:

*Error: Uncaught [TypeError: parentStateSetter is not a function]*

Here is the component where the function is defined:

```
  const CalendarWrapper = () => {
  // the parentState will be set by its child component - Calendar
  const [parentState, setParentState] = useState(false);

  // make wrapper function to give child so parent state can be set
  const wrapperSetParentState = useCallback(
    (val) => {
      setParentState(val);
    },
    [setParentState]
  );

  return (
    <Row>
      <Calendar
        parentState={parentState}
        parentStateSetter={wrapperSetParentState}
      />
      <Flyout parentState={parentState} />
    </Row>
  );
};
export default CalendarWrapper;
```

Here is the component where the function is called:

```
function Calendar({ parentStateSetter, parentState }) {

  const [childState, setChildState] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    parentStateSetter(childState);
  }, [parentStateSetter, childState]);

  const handleDateSelect = (e) => {
    //pass slider's event value to child's state
    setChildState(!childState);
  };

  ........................
```

Test:

```
describe("Calendar Component", () => {
  it("That the div for the calender exists", () => {
    const toggleInstance = shallow(<Calendar />);
    const element = toggleInstance.hasClass("col s12");
    expect(element).toBe(true);
  });

  it("renders without crashing", () => {
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    ReactDOM.render(<Calendar />, div);
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
  });
});
```

Comment: it's because in your test you render `Calendar` without the props it needs: `<Calendar />`